# Interacting with detected Objects

Tags: python

Goal: I have one large, interactive image, depicting several different buttons/symbols. Depending on which symbol it is, I want my program to click on the right one.

My attempt so far: Using cv2.matchTemplate() in Python, I could successfully identify everything that I needed to, as well as create copies that framed the right template with rectangles. No problems with the detection itself, the symbols are quite simple.

So far so good, but how do I proceed from there to interact with the original image on which I want to perform the clicks? I know that there are several modules to control mouse events, but the problem I have is that all the detection is based on the copy, and not the interactive original.

Comment: " *all the detection is based on the copy, and not the interactive original* "here is not clear to me

Comment: I've taken a screenshot ("copy") of an interactive game. More specifically, multiple, as the program progresses. Using those, the program detects the symbols. Which means, it only does so on the screenshot, and not on the original "game".

Comment: Then this is not opencv and computer-vision related question !

Comment: you have to use modules like `PyAutoGUI` or `pynput` to click in original game - `CV` doesn't have function to do this. It doesn't matter that you work with screenshot. You have to only keep original size of screenshot to get coordinates (x,y) for click in original size. If you rescaled screenshot then you will have to rescale coordinates for click.

Comment: BTW: [Programming a Bot to Play the "Sushi Go Round" Flash Game](https://inventwithpython.com/blog/2014/12/17/programming-a-bot-to-play-the-sushi-go-round-flash-game/)